# Simple SQL subquery -- homework

Tags: sql, subquery

Hey guys I have a homework question I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. I was hoping you guys could help me out.

The question is as follows:

> Find the trip id and trip name for each trip whose maximum group size
>   is greater than the maximum group size of every trip that has the type
>   'hiking'

So in the db I have a table called Trip and it has the fields required (TripID, TripName, Type, MaxGrpSize).

This is the code I have so far

```
SELECT TripID, TripName
FROM Trip
WHERE MaxGrpSize > 
    (SELECT MAX(MaxGrpSize)
    FROM Trip
    WHERE Type='Hiking');
```

Can anyone tell me if I am even approaching this problem the right way or if I'm way off here. Thanks.

Comment: I see no problem with the SQL. Why don't you check your query on real data? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Yeah I have and it did return a result, I was just worried that I wasn't going about it the right way, but the result seems correct. Thanks for the help guys I guess its good.

Answer (score 2):

I create a table for your test,
I am not sure what result that your expect.

```
Table: trip
Column: 
1 - TripID     (int 5) PK
2 - TripName   (varchar 10)
3 - Type       (varchar 10)
4 - MaxGrpSize (int 5)

TripID TripName Type   MaxGrpSize
00001  Trip1    Hiking 10
00002  Tyip2    Hiking 10
00003  Trip3    T3     20
```

If I run your sql, result has been return:

```
TripID TripName
00003  Trip3
```

I know what result that you want, please wait...

```
SELECT TripID, TripName 
FROM Trip WHERE MaxGrpSize=(
     SELECT MAX(MaxGrpSize)     
     FROM Trip WHERE Type='Hiking')
```

I think that the sql what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Koi, I tried with the database we were given and it did return a result, my main concern was that I wasn't going about it the right way but it seems correct so I think its okay. I just needed another set of eyes to relieve my anxiety, these 6 week courses give me sweats sometimes :P

Comment: The latest sql will return the max size of value in 'MaxGrpSize' and the type is 'Hiking'